# Free complex struct from task_struct in linux KERNEL 2.4

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, redhat

I added to the task_struct (in sched.h) a pointer that points to a complex struct. 
First of all in INIT_TASK macro I initialized it with NULL.
I added 2 new syscalls:

- One that allocates this complex struct by using kmalloc.
- Second that frees the complex struct by using kfree.

Now my problem is that if a process has the complex struct in its task_struct (the pointer is no more NULL) but it is dead BEFORE the user uses the second syscall to free the complex struct from the memory I have a memory leak in the KERNEL...

How I can solve this issue?

Can I add refactor a function (in the KERNEL) with additional code that will free the complex struct from the memory before the process dies, no matter in what way??

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Interesting question, well done. Hope you get the answer fast!

Comment: Mainline kernel handles release of complex structures inside `task_struct` in [`free_task`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.2/source/kernel/fork.c#L160). Depending on the semantics of your struct this may or may not be applicable.